# If $M$ is a finite $k[x]$-module, then $\dim_k \operatorname{coker} x - \dim_k \ker x=\dim_{k(x)} M\otimes_{k[x]} k(x)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $M$ be a finitely generated $k[x]$-module and consider the morphism given by multiplication by $x$, which we also denote $x$. I *think* it is true that
$$\dim_k \operatorname{coker} x - \dim_k \ker x=\dim_{k(x)} M\otimes_{k[x]} k(x),$$
but I failed to prove it.

It is indeed true in the simplest of cases: if $M=k[x]$, then $\ker x=0$ and $\operatorname{coker} x=k$, so that $1+0=\dim_{k(x)} k(x) =1$. But I don't know how to prove it in general.

Comment: A quick way of seeing this is to use the structure theorem of finite modules over a pid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $k$ is a field (I take this from the context), $k[x]$ is a PID and so, we know $M$ is the direct sum of copies of $k[x]$ and torsion modules each of the form $k[x]/(p(x))$ for nonzero $p(x)\in k[x].$ Your proposed equality is additive for direct sums and you have dealt with the free part, so we can assume $M$ has this latter form. The RHS is then zero, so we have to check the LHS is zero. First assume $x$ does not divide $p(x).$ Then the constant term $p_0=x((p(x)-p_0)/x)$ is nonzero, so $x$ is invertible on $M$ and the two dimensions on the left are both zero. Now let $p(x)=x^m q(x)$ where $m\ge 1$ and $x$ doesn't divide $q.$ By the Chinese Remainder theorem, $M=k[x]/(x^m)\oplus k[x]/(q).$ The left hand summand remains to be considered. For it, the kernel and cokernel in your equality are $x^{m-1}k[x]/x^mk[x]$ and $k[x]/xk[x]$ respectively, and both have dimension one, so this verifies the equality.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I think that we can avoid dividing into two cases by observing that the torsion modules have finite dimension over $k$ and so we can use the additivity of dimensions on exact sequences to conclude that $\dim_k \ker = \dim_k \operatorname{coker}$.